# What captcha system to use in Ruby on Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, security, captcha

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to add *captcha* to my forms.

What do you advice? What is "the best" and the most widely used captcha system for Ruby on Rails applications? Where I can find some good documentation?

Answer (score 4):

Personally I'm not a fan of recaptcha, simply because I find the text so hard to read - even though it's for a good cause etc..

Have you considered doing something like asking a simple question instead (what is 4 plus 2), or another good one I've seen is a jquery slider that you have to move to prove you're human.

If you do want to stick with a captcha  system, also check out [Recommendations for a captcha on Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859139/recommendations-for-a-captcha-on-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: I personally despise captcha and agree with Matt here.  Asking question or a slider would be much more preferable in my opinion.

Comment: What makes you think a person cannot automate slider moving with javascript? or you think computers cannot calculate 4+2? :P but OCR is something computers struggle on.. Note that people put captchas on their site.. so people don't over create acocunts.. if you site is targetted.. i'm pretty sure math and slider idea will fail..

Answer (score 1):

I used rack-recaptcha which is a great gem and it is very easy to use, you can find the doc at [github](https://github.com/achiu/rack-recaptcha) but it is pretty simple:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-recaptcha', :require => 'rack/recaptcha'
```

Application.rb:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
# ...
  config.gem 'rack-recaptcha', :lib => 'rack/recaptcha'
  config.middleware.use Rack::Recaptcha, :public_key => 'KEY', :private_key => 'SECRET'
end
```

*NOTE: You can get your public and private keys in the [recaptcha page](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha)*

Application_helper.rb or whatever helper you want it in.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include Rack::Recaptcha::Helpers
end
```

Application_controller.rb or whatever controller you want it in.

```
module ApplicationController
  include Rack::Recaptcha::Helpers
end
```

That is all the setup that you will need for it to work. It also has a test mode, simply add `Rack::Recaptcha.test_mode! :return => false` to your spec helper.

I really encourage you to check the full [doc](https://github.com/achiu/rack-recaptcha).

Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Please visit the link https://github.com/galetahub/simple-captcha will describe more about simple-captcha

Answer (score 0):

I have used recaptcha in a RoR project and it is working fine in production without any issues. I would recommend that.

For a list of available options, look [here](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_captcha.html)

Answer (score -1):

Don't know much about Ruby on rails but I know ReCpatcha is most easiest and it's ran by google so you know it's good haha

found a link http://ambethia.com/recaptcha/

Comment: I also use ReCaptcha and it was easy to integrate in our Rails App. I think it is a good one, because many people are familiar with it and it is save.